# How to get "this" scope in custom control constructor in WPF

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have extended the WPF Checkbox and built a Customcontrol, so I can add features to the checkbox.

My constructor looks like this

```
static MyCheckBox()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(MyCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCheckBox)));
}
```

Now I want to add an handler:

```
Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, OnValidationError);
```

But I don't have the `this` scope in the static constructor. How can I solve that?

Basically what I am trying to do is, to set an dependency property I created (IsValid9 to `true` or `false`, when the `Validation.Error` Event gets called. Therefore I need to register the handler.

Comment: add a public non-static ctor: `public MyCheckBox()
{Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, OnValidationError);}`

Comment: @jberger: Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

[The this-Pointer always points to the current instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx). But a static constructor is called before initializing any instance, so there cannot be a pointer to an instance. That's why you can't use.

You therefore need an instance first. And the very first action a new instance performs is it's constructor:

```
public class MyCheckBox
{
    static MyCheckBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MyCheckBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCheckBox)));
    }

    public MyCheckBox() 
    {
        Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, OnValidationError);
    }

    void OnValidationError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a public non-static constructor:

```
public MyCheckBox() 
{
    Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, OnValidationError);
}
```